# ASP Classic Code Can Someone Interpret What This Code Does?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Am I nuts or ignorant (both very possible) or does this code do nothing?

I am maintaining a legacy site written by a 3rd party company, so there is really no-one involved with the site that I can ask.

I understand they are looping through a recordset and getting the number of the last record. But I don't understand what the "if" block is doing. In psuedocode it seems to be saying "If I have a number and subtract from it that same number, after having divided it by four and then multiplied it by four and it does not equal zero...then"

When can that not equal zero (except when you generate a divide by zero error)? <-- ignore that, I was thinking backwards, you could get 0/4 but not 4/0. Rest of the question remains however.

The only thing I can think of is if the record number were negative? Is that possible, I don't claim to be an expert in ASP Classic but am not aware that could happen.

Anyone know what I am missing here?

```
do while not rs.EOF 
    recordNum = recordNum + 1
    rs.MoveNext 
loop

rs.MoveFirst

if recordNum-((recordNum\4)*4) > 0 then
    recordNumber = (recordNum\4)+1
else
    recordNumber = (recordNum\4)
end if
```

Comment: This makes little sense -- it will never be > 0 and thus always go into the Else.  Not unless there is additional logic prior to the loop...

Comment: The logic there is all self contained. Some things happen later but I don't see any way the IF....>0 ever evaluates as anything other than 0. At first I thought it was some sort of code to do something at 4 (as someone else mention) but What changes at four? 4 -((4/4)*4) = 0 but 1-((1/4)*4)=0 as well. When is a number divided by four then multiplied by four and then is subtracted from itself anything other than zero, unless it's either zero or a negative number to start with? (x/4)*4 will always be x and x-x will always be zero if x is greater than zero to start with.

Comment: It will never equal anything but 0: x - x always = 0 :) -- Doesn't matter if it's negative or positive: (-x - (-x)) = -x + x = 0...

Comment: I've had a closer look and I've deleted my counting to 4 answer, that isn't what it does.  As you say (x/4)*4 will always equal 0. I wonder if whoever wrote the code originally might have left a set of brackets out.  I think (recordNum-((recordNum\4))*4) > 0 would be true if recordNum had a value of between 0 and 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as pointed out in a now deleted answer, `recordNum\4` returns the integer portion of the division since the backslash operator in VBScript is used for **Integer Division**, while the ordiary slash (/) is used for floating point division.

Here are some sample values:

```
recordNum | recordNumber
----------|-------------
    0     |     0
    1     |     1
    2     |     1
    3     |     1
    4     |     1
    5     |     2
    6     |     2
    7     |     2
    8     |     2
    9     |     3
```

So this value is not the number of records, it rather answers questions like "how many groups of fours items I have"?

Now based on that, whoever wrote the code can then know how many table rows to display for example:

```
For x=1 To recordNumber
    Response.Write("<tr>")
    Response.Write("<td>...</td>")
    Response.Write("<td>...</td>")
    Response.Write("<td>...</td>")
    Response.Write("<td>...</td>")
    Response.Write("</tr>")
Next
```

Comment: Well you learn something new every day. So `\ ` would pretty much be the compliment of `%`

Comment: @JonP yep, like yin and yang! ;)

Comment: something new to learn, my respects to @ShadowWizard (btw i think so that OP must accept this answer)

Comment: @Rafael to be honest I learned this only now as well by looking to solve this "mystery". Worth to try and help! :)

Comment: I did not know that about VB script. If I had seen % I would have gotten it immediately. So when I asked "am I nuts or just ignorant" the answer was "ignorant". Thanks!

Comment: @valis we are all ignorant, it's totally fine... glad I could help and thanks for making me learn something new too! :-)

Answer (score 1):

it's a kind of pagination algorithm <strike>that does nothing meaningful, only wasting your cpu cycles, that **IF** in 100% of cases  will result in 0</strike>

and btw: *you will never reach a divide by zero exception, because divide 0 by 4 = 0*.

Comment: Not sure I follow that, could you explain? say the number is X. wouldn't the code be evaluated as x-((x/4)*4) ? The innermost operation is the....now that I typed it out I don't know what I was thinking. Obviously 0/4 != 4/0.

Comment: Actually it does seem to have a purpose - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this conversation (even though it's been answered); the above 'algorithm' counts the number of 'pages' in the data and allows for the fact that there may be just over *n* pages but not quite *n*+1.  Another way of doing this would be to read in a scalar value:

```
sqlString = "SELECT COUNT(id_field) AS total FROM table WHERE criteria = TRUE "
...
'Read data into array and pass to variable.
...
Dim maxPages
maxPages = recs \ 4 + (((recs \ 4) <> (recs / 4)) And 1)
```

Looping through the records, as per your post, Valis, is a huge waste of time.